# A Script that can run in any directory

Tags: python

Currently, I have created a code that makes graphs from data in .csv files. However, I can only run the code if that code is present in the folder with the csv files. How can I make the the script file so that it doesn't have to be in the same directory as the .csv files. Also, I would like that same script to read every csv file in that other directory.

Why is the code below wrong?

```
Here=os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
directory = "path of directory"
listing = os.listdir(directory)
for files in listing:
    if files.endswith('.csv'):  
    full_name = os.path.join(Here,files)
    df=pd.read_csv(full_name)
```

Comment: Since you're listing the files in the current directory, you don't need to join the names with `Here` at all (so you don't need to assign it).  The empty string as a directory name almost certainly defaults to the current directory (the only reasonable alternative is for it to be an error).  If you specified some other value for `directory`, you'd need to join the name with `directory`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just set `directory="/path/to/fldr/with/csv"`

and      `full_name = os.path.join(directory,files)`

Comment: for some reason when I do that, i am getting an error message that no such file or directory. Do you know why? I have the correct path and everything

Comment: @user2614937 Going to go ahead and say that if it says there's no such file or directory, something is wrong with your path. Print it out to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is wrong; you'll need to accept a argument that tells your script where to find the CSV files:

```
import argparse

def import_function(sourcedir):
    for filename in os.listdir(sourcedir):
        csvfilename = os.path.join(sourcedir, filename)
        with open(csvfilename) as csvfile:
            reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
            for row in reader:
                # etc.    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser('CSV importer')
    parser.add_argument('sourcedir', default='.')
    options = parser.parse_args()
    import_function(options.sourcedir)
```

Now your script accepts one command-line argument, a path to the directory to list your files in:

```
python yourscript.py /path/to/directory
```

The default is to look in the current directory still.

Answer (score 0):

You are listing an empty directory (`directory = ''`).

To get the current directory you need `os.getcwd()`.

I don't get what's the problem in specifying the directory to operate in. It could be done with command line parameters (look at `sys.argv`).

Comment: You can use `'.'` for the current directory without using `os.getcwd()`, can't you?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler sure! But listdir returns the content of the directory while getcwd the directory path itself. Since he uses it to compose an absolute path I thought it would be useful to let him know also that call :)

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the path you want to the variable 'Here', but then you are creating an empty string variable 'directory' and using that to provide the listing.  Your listing will only contain files within your base folder (where you code is) because your are only searching for files in directory "".  I think what you intend is to use 'Here' to do your listing

```
directory = Here
```

Comment: That continues to force the script to be in the same directory as the CSV files, doesn't it?